# How to group by months from starting date, ending date and categorical variables

Tags: python, numpy, group-by, date-range

there is a list of HR:

```
  Department       Start         End  Salary per month
0      Sales  01.01.2020  30.04.2020              1000
1     People  01.05.2020  30.07.2022              3000
2  Marketing  01.02.2020  30.12.2099              3200
3      Sales  01.03.2020  01.08.2023              1200
4   Engineer  01.04.2020  30.12.2099              3500
```

Using python
I'm wondering how to group total salary by month (starting from very beginning of the first employee) and also by the department

I have tried to group salaries by date range but don't know how to also group with the department and show each department in each column

```
month_starts = pd.date_range(data.start.min(),data.end.max(),freq = 'MS').to_numpy()
contained = np.logical_and(
    np.greater_equal.outer(month_starts, data['start'].to_numpy()),
    np.less.outer(month_starts,data['end'].to_numpy())
)
masked = np.where(contained, np.broadcast_to(data[['salary_per_month']].transpose(), contained.shape),np.nan)
df = pd.DataFrame(masked, index = month_starts).agg('sum',axis=1).to_frame().reset_index()
df.columns = ['month', 'total_cost']
```

Expected output:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCsx3.png)

Comment: To group by month, use `df.groupby([pd.to_datetime(df['start']).dt.to_period('M'), 'Department']).sum()` (for the Year-Month), or `df.groupby([pd.to_datetime(df['start']).dt.month, 'Department']).sum()` for the months independently of the year (1-12).

Comment: what's about the ending date?

Comment: Do you want to explode the start/end into several months? Please provide a clear reproducible example (no image!) and the matching expected output

Comment: Correct, I want to see to cost for each department for each month. But there is only list of employees with the contract starting and ending date with salary for each month.

Comment: I see, I updated your question with a reproducible input and provided an answer

Answer (score 0):

You can [`repeat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) your rows and increment the periods, then [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) :

```
s = pd.to_datetime(df['Start'], dayfirst=True).dt.to_period('M')
e = pd.to_datetime(df['End'], dayfirst=True).dt.to_period('M')

n = (e-s).apply(lambda x: x.n)

(df.assign(Date=s)
   .loc[df.index.repeat(n+1)]
   .assign(Date=lambda d: d['Date']+d.groupby(level=0).cumcount())
   .pivot_table(index='Date', columns='Department', values='Salary per month',
                aggfunc='sum', fill_value=0)
)
```

Output:

```
Department  Engineer  Marketing  People  Sales
Date                                          
2020-01            0          0       0   1000
2020-02            0       3200       0   1000
2020-03            0       3200       0   2200
2020-04         3500       3200       0   2200
2020-05         3500       3200    3000   1200
...              ...        ...     ...    ...
2099-08         3500       3200       0      0
2099-09         3500       3200       0      0
2099-10         3500       3200       0      0
2099-11         3500       3200       0      0
2099-12         3500       3200       0      0

[960 rows x 4 columns]
```

Comment: @nguyenanh yes of course, subtracting the 2 periods gives a number of periods, this code is to extract the integer part